# eww: error in process sentinel: url-cookie-generate-header-lines: Wrong type argument: listp, \.\.\

Tags: eww

I'm doing `M-x eww` with Emacs-24.5 -Q on Debian 8, for example with the address "http://google.com" (or just "google.com").  And receive the error message in the subject line, in other words: I can't use eww at all for internet addresses, what the heck is going on?

Comment: Have you tried just google.com without http:// ?

Comment: @Name yes, updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glenn Morris on the emacs.bugs mailing list pointed out a bug of emacs-24.5. One has to delete the cookie caching file saved in `url-cookie-file` because it can became saved in an incorrect format. http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21370